# How to access same database by both asp.net web application and WPF desktop application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, sql-server-2008

My question can be simple or easy. I have created two applications one is asp.net website and second is WPF Desktop application. Both are accessing same sql-server database. Question are:

> 1. What are the best hosting websites to register a website?
> 2. Once a website is registered  how to access that SQL-server database placed on server by desktop application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answers

1. Godaddy, bigrock, somee.com**  are good hosting providers
2. Use the same **ConnectionString** in both website and WPF application.

Comment: what will be connection string?

Comment: you will get connectionstring when you will buy space on servers for hosting.

Comment: I want to publish muy website via FTP. i go to build->publish->ftp-> ftp://nrcs.somee.com ->publish->entered my username and password.

now as publication starts it says that it is unable to upload 'aboutus.aspx'.Access denied(550).

How to solve this problem?

Comment: first publish site at your local file system. then use any ftp file uploader software like filezilla and upload with that. This is the process which i follow to upload sites.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should develop an API and host it as a webservice somewhere (azure?) and let the webapp and wpf app access only that service, not the database directly.

Comment: Hi thanks's for quick response. can you please describe your answer in detail.;)

Comment: are you familiar with webservices? basically you need to abstract all your business logic and data access away from your user interface and put it behind a service.

Comment: you could use MVVM in your UI (especially the one that is WPF) but it is not essential. I think you should go back and do some reading... ;)